# Currency pipe with a dynamic currency variable in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, currency-pipe

I am using CurrencyPipe with my application,

The following works,

```
 <div class="price">{{123 | currConvert | currency:'USD':true:'3.2-2'}}</div>
```

Now i have to pass the currency from the model variable, this is what i am doing,

```
  ngOnInit() {
         this.selectedCurrency = 'USD';
     }
```

and in template,

```
   <div class="price">{{123 | currConvert | currency:{{selectedCurrency}}:true:'3.2-2'}}</div>
```

it gives me a template parse error. what is the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't nest `{{}}`

```
   <div class="price">{{123 | currConvert | currency:selectedCurrency:true:'3.2-2'}}</div>
```

Comment: that works, is there a event for the component that i can use whenever there is a change in component say it could be a label, which event to use?

Comment: actually i have a parent component and i set the selectedcurrency in the parentcomponent , this pipe is applied in another component. i get the selectedcurrency through localstorage on the child component. but it does not seem to get the updated selectedCurrency

Comment: I would need to see more code. You can try to inject `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}` and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` after you update `selectedCurrency`.

Comment: do i have to use local storage for that? '

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean. You don't *have to* use local storage, for anything, if you don't want to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291902/how-to-notify-the-parent-component-variable-changes-to-another-component

Answer (score 0):

when item is possibly null:

```
   <div class="price">{{123 | currConvert |  currency: item?.currency ?? '' }}</div>
```