# How to notify the parent component variable changes to another component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing the internatiolization in the application , There are many components inside the parent component.

In app.component.ts, i am setting the current selected currency as follows,

```
 ngOnInit() {      
    this.selectedLanguage = "EN";
    this.selectedCurrency = "EUR";
    //also setting to local storage
    localStorage.setItem('currency', this.selectedCurrency);
}
```

There is another child component where i have to use the **selectedcurrency** in the pipe , so i am getting  the **selectedcurrency** in  as follows

```
export class EveComponent  implements OnInit {
     selectedCurrency :string;
     ngOnInit() {
         this.selectedCurrency = localStorage.getItem("currency");
     }
}
```

but this does not seems to work, when changes happening in parent.
and my pipe as follows,

```
 <div class="price">{{123 | currConvert | currency:selectedCurrency:true:'3.2-2'}}</div>
```

Now when i change the selectedCurrency on my parent page, i want that to be applied on the EveComponent as well. How to do that with angular2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 - If your child component is the direct child of your appComponent , you should be able to use an `@Input` in the child.**

parent component template :

```
   <child-cmp [selectedCurrency]="selectedCurrency"></child-cmp>
```

and then inside the child component

```
export class EveComponent  implements OnInit {
     @Input() selectedCurrency :string;
}
```

no need to to use your localStorage service anymore in child.

**2- The Child component is not a direct child of the parent component , which in this case , you can create an eventEmitter :**

Inside you localStorage service :

```
export class LocalStorageService{
    $currencyChanges = new EventEmitter<any>();

    public setItem(item){
        // what ever u where doing , plus : 
        this.$currencyChanges.emit(item);
    }
}
```

And then inside the child , you've got the service already , so u can :

export class EveComponent  implements OnInit {

```
 ngOnInit() {
     localStorage.$currencyChanges.subscribe((changes)=>{
         this.selectedCurrency = changes;

     });
 }
```

Comment: LocalStorageService is not a service its a component

Comment: how should i modify this? it keeps an error saying $currencyChanges cannot be found

Comment: What do you mean localStorage is not a service ? What is is then ? Can u share it's code , ?

Comment: Basically , you need a service and an event emitter , that's about it

Comment: can you mdofify the answer please

Comment: @Sajeetharan , modify to what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136015/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-milad).

Comment: I think you need to provide the code behind localSorage,

Comment: can you come to the chat

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a good idea to modify the model in `ngOnInit()`.
`ngOnInit()` is called by change detection and changes during change detection usually cause problems like the exception "Expression has changed after it has been checked".

This should work better:

```ts
 constructor() {
     this.selectedCurrency = localStorage.getItem("currency");
 }
```

Code in the constructor also has some disadvantages (like with testing).

Another workaround is therefore

```ts
 constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

 ngOnInit() {
     this.selectedCurrency = localStorage.getItem("currency");
     this.cdRef.detectChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Check if `localStorage.getItem(...)` actually gets a value. Perhaps the other component wasn't yet able to set it.

Comment: it gets the same value which is set by default, i want it to set the value when i change the drop down and set in parent page

Comment: I'm sure if the value is assigned to the field and change detection is run, then the pipe will use that value. You can try to reproduce in a Plunker so I can investigate. Without that I don't see how I would be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: additional information, child component is loaded initially with the parent at the same time, would that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question its seems like to be case for the standard `Parent-> Child` communication or `sibling->sibling` communication.

I observed that you are save the `currency` in local storage which means you are trying to use 'localStorage' as a sharedService for values[at least for `currency`] (and its not observable)

Did you try treating `selectedCurrency` as an input in `child` and `parentCurrency` initializing it. `parentCurrency` may be initialized/updated by itself or any other sibling.
**Which means Your parent should act as a mediator for siblings as far a message passing is concerned.**

**Child**

```
export class EveComponent  implements OnInit {
     @Input()
     selectedCurrency :string;
     ngOnInit() {
         this.selectedCurrency = localStorage.getItem("currency");
     }
}
```

**Parent Template**

```
<child [selectedCurrency ]="parentCurrency"></child>
```

**Parent**

```
ngOnInit() {      
    this.selectedLanguage = "EN";
    this.parentCurrency = "EUR"; // this property can be changed/updated and expected to be observed.
    //also setting to local storage
    localStorage.setItem('currency', this.parentCurrency);
}
```

A `Github` sample for the issue will definitely help debug whats going on.

Comment: @can you put a demo on github reporducing your case ? hard to know whats going on without the full story.

Comment: what i want to do is actually to implement internatioalization, i have dropdown to set the currency . when it is set on the home page, it should be applied for all the child components using the pipe